# Caching ajax responses

Tags: jquery, ajax, caching

For an identical `url` and `myObj`, and assuming that the server doesn't provide any headers not to cache, will most modern browsers cache the response for sequential requests?  If `myObj` is different, please confirm that the response will not be cached.

```
$.getJSON(url, myObj,function( json ) {console.log(json);});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the URL and data arguments are the same, the response will normally be cached. Browsers use the same logic for caching AJAX `GET` responses as they do for caching web pages.

Comment: Thanks Barmar,  I figured so for a given URL, but wasn't sure for the passed data argument.

Comment: The passed data is appended to the URL as a query string.